# Regex to match strings that begin with specific word and after that words seperated by slashes

Tags: regex, prefix, slash

So i want to match all strings of the form with a regex

```
(word1|word2|word3)/some/more/text/..unlimited parts.../more
```

so it starts with specific word and it does not end with /

examples to match:

```
word1/ok/ready
word2/hello
word3/ok/ok/ok/ready
```

What i want in the end is when i have a text with above 3 examples in it (spread around in a random text), that i receive an array with those 3 matches after doing regex.exec(text);

Anybody an idea how to start?
Thanks!

Comment: @AndyLester is right. Here are a few hints: `[^/]` matches anything except a slash; `+` means match one or more of the preceding item.

Comment: I understand.. i did try and i was able to match the prefix but not the others :)

Comment: **Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
^(word1|word2|word3)(/\w+)+$
```

If you're using this in an environment where you need to delimit the regex with slashes, then you'll need to escape the inner slash:

```
/^(word1|word2|word3)(\/\w+)+$/
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to capture the second part, make it a non-capturing group:

```
/^(word1|word2|word3)(?:\/\w+)+$/
                      ^^ Add those two characters
```

I *think* this is what you want, but who knows:

```
var input = '';
input += 'here is a potential match word1/ok/ready that is followed by another ';
input += 'one word2/hello and finally the last one word3/ok/ok/ok/ready';

var regex = /(word1|word2|word3)(\/\w+)+/g;
var results = []

while ((result = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
    results.push(result[0].split('/'));
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks! although i does not work as intented, if i do /^(word1|word2|word3)(\/\w+)+$/.exec("word1/ok/ok"), then i get ["word1/ok/ok", "word1", "/ok"] while i should only get the first one :) Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Thanks i added ?: to word1 also and now it works fine

Comment: it works fine to match only one occurence, but actually what i want to do is use that regex to find ALL matches in a text. I've updated my question, please have a look

Comment: I'm sorry, wasn't clear enough about my intentions. Please have a look again. I know that i need to remove the ^ and $, but then i'm stuck..